# Building Web Applications using Team Build 2010

Tags: web-applications

Having recently upgraded to TFS2010 I am having a problem building web applications.  In TFS2005 the build.proj file included steps to setup IIS on the build server.

Could anyone provide advice as to how I can build these projects using TFS2010.

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UpgradeTemplate to run your old .proj file.

Was this build working in TFS-2005??